# VBA determine approval status for unique transaction IDs (numerous similar IDs)

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner in VBA and have no idea how to write this code despite spending weeks on it.

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

---

**order_id** | **order_status**

12345 | complete

12345 | cancelled

67890 | complete

13579 | pending

13579 | complete

24680 | cancelled

24680 | cancelled

24680 | complete

24680 | complete

24680 | complete

---

As seen above, I have a list of order ids of differing numbers of status, some with only 1 "completed" and others with a combination of "completed", "cancelled", "pending" etc. I need to write a code that looks through each set of order IDs and determine its validated status.

In order or priority, if the order_id set contains at least 1 "pending", the validated_status will be "pending". If there is no "pending" status, and the order_id set contains at least 1 "cancelled", the validated_status will be "rejected", and only if ALL order_status of the order_id set contains "completed" will the validated status be set as "approved". In the above example, the following validated status will be:

---

**order_id** | **validated_status**

12345 | rejected

67890 | approved

13579 | pending

24680 | rejected

---

Here is my current code that I have worked out so far, but excel crashes everytime this code is run (did I enter an infinite loop accidentally?).

```
Sub newtest()

Dim i, j, k as integer
Dim LastRow as Long
Dim firstid, validated_status_range, order_id_set as range

With worksheets("To update")

    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).end(xlUp).Row

    'Remove duplicate order_ids and copy into validated_status worksheet
    'column H contains order_ids
    .Range("H2:H" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("validated_status").Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Unique:=True

    'start from 2 because of header row
    Set firstid = .Range("H" & 2)


    For j = 1 to LastRow

        Do until firstid.offset(j,0).value <> firstid.value
            j = j + 1
        Loop

        For k = 2 to j

            Set validated_status_range = Worksheets("validated_status").Range("B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Range("H" & k).Value, Worksheets("validated_status").Range("A:A")))
            Set order_id_set = .range("H" & k & ":H" & j)
            Set status_return = order_id_set.Find("return")
            Set status_pending = order_id_set.Find("pending")
            Set status_invalid = order_id_set.Find("invalid")
            Set status_cancelled = order_id_set.Find("cancelled")
            Set status_completed = order_id_set.Find("completed")

            If Not status_pending Is Nothing Then
                validated_status_range.Value = "Rejected"
            ElseIf Not status_return Is Nothing Then
                validated_status_range.Value = "Rejected"
            ElseIf Not status_invalid Is Nothing Then
                validated_status_range.Value = "Rejected"
            ElseIf Not status_cancelled Is Nothing Then
                validated_status_range.Value = "Rejected"
            ElseIf Not status_completed Is Nothing Then
                validated_status_range.Value = "Approved"
            End If

            k = k + j

        Next k

    Next j

End with

End Sub
```

This is probably not the most elegant way of writing a code for my problem but I'm hoping all of you kind souls can shed some light on this for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you say that *"column H contains order_ids"* and consequently `.Range("H2:H" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter...` code line is actually copying their unique values from "To update" sheet column H to "validated_status" sheet column A

but in subsequent code, all `Find()` methods are called on `order_id_set` range which you set as `Set order_id_set = .range("H" & k & ":H" & j)` , i.e. to column H again, while it must be a different column

so, assuming that "validated_status" values are in "To update" sheet column I, here's a possible code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Worksheets("To update")
        For Each cell In .Range("H2:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'loop through "order_id" column
            dict(cell.value) = dict(cell.value) & cell.Offset(, 1)  ' joining all "order_status" values from column I associated to the same "order_id"
        Next
        For Each key In dict.keys
            Select Case True
                Case InStr(dict(key), "pending") > 0
                    dict(key) = "pending"
                Case InStr(dict(key), "cancelled") > 0
                    dict(key) = "rejected"
                Case InStr(dict(key), "complete") > 0
                    dict(key) = "approved"
            End Select
        Next
    End With
    With Worksheets("validated_status")
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .ClearContents
            .Resize(1).value = Array("order_id", "validated_status")
            .Resize(UBound(dict.keys) + 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
            .Resize(UBound(dict.keys) + 1, 1).Offset(1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

should you want to stick to `AdvancedFilter` approach, then you may code:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim validateSht As Worksheet: Set validateSht = Worksheets("validated_status")

    With Worksheets("To update")
        With .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("validated_status").Range("A1"), Unique:=True
            validateSht.Range("B1").value = "validated_status"
            For Each cell In validateSht.Range("A2", validateSht.Cells(validateSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
                Select Case True
                    Case Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Cells, cell.value, .Offset(, 1), "pending") > 0
                        cell.Offset(, 1).value = "pending"
                    Case Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Cells, cell.value, .Offset(, 1), "cancelled") > 0
                        cell.Offset(, 1).value = "rejected"
                    Case Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Cells, cell.value, .Offset(, 1), "complete") > 0
                        cell.Offset(, 1).value = "approved"
                End Select
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code for a standard public module code sheet seems to do what you expect.

```
Option Explicit

Sub lastStatus()
    Dim arr As Variant, d As Long, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2

        For d = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not dict.exists(arr(d, 1)) Then
                Select Case LCase(arr(d, 2))
                    Case "pending"
                        dict.Add Key:=arr(d, 1), Item:="pending"
                    Case "cancelled"
                        dict.Add Key:=arr(d, 1), Item:="rejected"
                    Case "completed"
                        dict.Add Key:=arr(d, 1), Item:="approved"
                    Case Else
                        'do nothing
                End Select
            Else
                Select Case LCase(arr(d, 2))
                    Case "pending"
                        dict.Item(arr(d, 1)) = "pending"
                    Case "cancelled"
                        If dict.Item(arr(d, 1)) <> "pending" Then _
                            dict.Item(arr(d, 1)) = "rejected"
                    Case Else
                        'do nothing
                End Select
            End If
        Next d

        .Cells(2, "D").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
        .Cells(2, "E").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]